# How to convert a WAMP stacked app running on a VPS to a scalable AWS app?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a web app running on php, mysql, apache on a virtual windows server. I want to redesign it so it is scalable (for fun so I can learn new things) on AWS.

I can see how to setup  an EC2 and dump it all in there but I want to make it scalable and take advantage of all the cool features on AWS.

I've tried googling but just can't find a simple guide (note - I have no command line experience of Linux)

Can anyone direct me to detailed resources that can lead me through the steps and teach me? Or alternatively, summarise the steps in an answer so I can research based on what you say.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS is growing and changing all the time, so there aren't a lot of books to help. Amazon offers [training](http://aws.amazon.com/aws-training/) that's excellent. I took their three day class on [Architecting with AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/aws-training/architect/) that seems to be just what you're looking for.

Of course, not everyone can afford to spend the travel time and money to attend a class. The [AWS re:Invent conference](http://reinvent.awsevents.com/) in November 2012 had a lot of sessions related to what you want, and most (maybe all) of the sessions have videos available online for free. Building Web Scale Applications With AWS is probably relevant ([slides](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/building-webscale-applications-architectures-with-aws-aws-reinvent-2012-arc205) and [video](http://www.youtube.com/v/2wZAN2_W6Ns?autoplay=1&rel=0&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer) available), as is Dissecting an Internet-Scale Application ([slides](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/arc303-dissecting-and-internet-scale-application) and [video](http://www.youtube.com/v/1YYPt5ox-fQ?autoplay=1&rel=0&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer) available).

A great way to understand these options better is by fiddling with your existing application on AWS. It will be easy to just move it to an EC2 instance in AWS, then start taking more advantage of what's available. The first thing I'd do is get rid of the MySql server on your own machine and use one offered with RDS. Once that's stable, create one or more read replicas in RDS, and change your application to read from them for most operations, reading from the main (writable) database only when you need completely current results.

Does your application keep any data on the web server, other than in the database? If so, get rid of all local storage by moving that data off the EC2 instance. Some of it might go to the database, some (like big files) might be suitable for S3. DynamoDB is a good place for things like session data.

All of the above reduces the load on the web server to just your application code, which helps with scalability. And now that you keep no state on the web server, you can use ELB and Auto-scaling to automatically run multiple web servers (and even automatically launch more as needed) to handle greater load.

Does the application have any long running, intensive operations that you now perform on demand from a web request? Consider not performing the operation when asked, but instead queueing the request using SQS, and just telling the user you'll get to it. Now have long running processes (or cron jobs or scheduled tasks) check the queue regularly, run the requested operation, and email the result (using SES) back to the user. To really scale up, you can move those jobs off your web server to dedicated machines, and again use auto-scaling if needed.

Do you need bigger machines, or perhaps can live with smaller ones? CloudWatch metrics can show you how much IO, memory, and CPU are used over time. You can use provisioned IOPS with EC2 or RDS instances to improve performance (at a cost) as needed, and use difference size instances for more memory or CPU.

All this AWS setup and configuration can be done with the AWS web console, or command-line tools, or SDKs available in many languages (Python's [boto library](https://github.com/boto/boto) is great). After learning the basics, look into CloudFormation to automate it better (I've written a [couple](http://blog.engelke.com/2012/12/19/learning-about-aws-cloudformation/) of [posts](http://blog.engelke.com/2012/12/28/provisioning-a-server-with-cloudformation/) about that so far).

That's a bit of the 10,000 foot high view of one approach. You'll need to discover the details of each AWS service when you try to use them. AWS has [good documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/) about all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you look at it, this is more of a comment than it is an answer, but it was too long to write as a comment.

What you're asking for really can't be answered on SO--it's a huge, complex question.  You're basically asking is *"How to I design a highly-scalable, durable application that can be deployed on a cloud-based platform?"*  The answer depends largely on:

- The specifics of your application--what does it do and how does it work?
- Your tolerance for downtime balanced against your budget
- Your present development and deployment workflow
- The resources/skill sets you have on-staff to support the application
- What your launch time frame looks like.

I run a software consulting company that specializes in consulting on Amazon Web Services architecture. About 80% of our business is investigating and answering these questions for our clients.  It's a multi-week long project each time.

However, to get you pointed in the right direction, I'd recommend that you look at [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/).  It's a PaaS-like service that abstracts away the underlying AWS resources, making AWS easier to use for developers who don't have a lot of sysadmin experience.  Think of it as "training wheels" for designing an autoscaling application on AWS.